# Naming of Excel sheets or tab in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2012, subreport

I am making a report in SSRS that will be exported to Excel. It displays data from all departments in organization.

The first sheet of the report will have a static name for e.g. "Master Report" and it will display data of all departments in single sheet.

Other sheets will have dynamic name depending on department and will display data of that particular department.

So it will become something like as shown in picture below.

[image]

I have already made the Master Report and now I want to display those individual department reports but problem is how do I name those sheets? Both these reports will use different data set. If I set the **InitialPageName** property of report to "Master Report" then it sets this name for all sheets. If I use an expression for e.g. **=First(Fields!Dept_Title.Value, "ALL_DEPARTMENTS")** then it picks up first department name and then use it for all sheets because as I told above, there are two different data sets.

Using subreport is of no help either because it doesn't show subreports InitialPageName as Excel sheet name and always uses Main reports name.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: For your report, are all departments groups within the same table? Or do they all have separate, distinct report items?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. If you are asking about relationship between "Master Report" and other department reports then there is no relation. These are two separate reports.

Comment: Ok I got the solution. Just came to know about Group PageName property. So now I have two tablix in my report. One is at top which is showing Main Report while other is below which will show department reports. I have set InitialPageName property of report to "Master Report" while in Group PageName property I have defined expression Fields!Dept_Title.Value and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. Just came to know about Group **PageName** property. So now I have two tablix in my report. One is at top which is showing Main Report while other is below which will show department reports. I have set **InitialPageName** property of report to "Master Report" while in Group PageName property of tablix2, I have defined expression **Fields!Dept_Title.Value** and it's working.